# Javascript: Get this prototype object name

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, jsobject

```
..
Class.prototype.property = function(){
return(this.prototypeobject.name);
}
..

oClass = new Class();
alert(oClass.property());
```

It's simple(or maybe not?). I just want to get the current prototype object name as String.
**Note:** `this.prototypeobject.name` doensn't work. It's just an example.

Comment: `return` isn't a function, `return this.prototypeobject.name;` is equivalent.

Comment: @RobG I don't get it. I know, that return isn't a function. I just want to return the Prototype object name as String(in my case "property").

Comment: What do you `.prototypeobject` expect to be? I've never heard of such property in [`Class`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/).

Comment: Can you show an example where you would need this?

Comment: @Bergi I want to call a function in the property function. The called function need to know from which property function it was called. Sure `callFunction('property')` in `Class.prototype.property` would do the trick, but i don't want to use String values, cause the posted parameter is always like the prototype object function.

Comment: You cannot. And what exactly does the `callFunction` need the caller's method name for?

Comment: The `callFunction` includes a ajax call to a php script. The php script needs to know, which function he should call.

Comment: How does the PHP script call a javascript function? If you are using JSONP, then you just should pass the callback's name as a literal. Or maybe create that dynamically and use a reference to the actual method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such reflection functionality. A function doesn't know itself other than by explicit reference ([`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) is deprecated), and function objects are not bound to any properties anyway so they cannot know the respective property name. Whenever you need a "method name", hardcode it as a string literal.

---

OK, there is something you could do (using a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/), you can change it to a function declaration for IE):

```
Constr.prototype.someProperty = function myFuncName(args…) {
    var propertyName = "";
    for (var p in this)
        if (this[p] == myFuncName) {
            propertyName = p;
            break;
        }
    alert("this function (myFuncName) was found on property '"
         +propertyName+"' of `this` object");
};

var inst = new Constr(…);
inst.someProperty(…); // alerts "… found on property 'someProperty' …"
```

However, this is an ugly hack and you should not use it.